# stuck at start up of integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt {\sin x} \sqrt{\cos^7 x}}$$

That's the given value. I was dividing denominator and numerator by $\cos^4
(x)$.

$$\int \frac{sec^4 \mathrm  dx}{\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\cos^7x}{\cos x}}}$$
$$\int \frac{sec^4 \mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\tan x}\cdot \sqrt{\cos^6x}}$$

But, my book wrote that

$$\int\frac{\sec^4x \mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\tan x}}$$

[image]

I have read a note in my book's context. They wrote that

**Note :** If m+n is real number than, you have to divide by $\cos^{m+n}x$ in this type of integral $$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin^mx \cos^nx}$$ then, you have take $\tan x=z$.

Why? Can't I prove that?

Comment: $$ \ \frac{1}{\cos^4 x} \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos^8 x}} \ \ ... $$

Comment: @boojum I think you mistook something $4^2=16$ Even, how can I get $\cos^8$?

Comment: $ \ (x^4)^2 \ = \ x^8 \ \ , $ not $ \ x^{16} \ \ . $

Comment: @boojum How can I get $\cos^8x$

Comment: $ \ \sqrt{(\cos x)^8} \ = \ (\cos x)^{8/2} \ = \ (\cos x)^4 \ \ . $

Comment: @boojum Hey! I can't find $8$. So, how can I divide $8$ by $2$

Comment: This line in your answer should read: $$  \int \frac{\sec^4 \mathrm  dx}{\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\cos^7x}{\cos^7 x}}} \ \ .$$  You want to split up $ \ \sqrt{\cos^8 x } \ $ between the two radicals.

Comment: @boojum If I square root $\cos^7$ than, I don't get $\cos^3$ either. Could you please write an answer.?

Comment: When you divide the numerator by $\cos ^4x$ you get $\sec^4x$. But you have not divided the denominator by $\cos^4x$ correctly. Instead you have divided the denominator just by $\cos x$.

Comment: You need to get yourself familiar with law of rational exponents. In particular note that $\sqrt[n] {x^m} =x^{m/n} $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh $$\cos^2x=\sqrt{\cos x}$$

Comment: No no no!! $\sqrt{\cos x} =\cos^{1/2}x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up from where you left off

$$\int \frac{(1 + \tan^2(x))\sec^2(x)}{\sqrt {\tan(x)}}dx$$

$u = \tan (x) \rightarrow \frac{du}{dx} = \sec^2(x) \rightarrow dx = \frac{1}{\sec^2(x)} du$

$$\int \frac{u^2 + 1}{\sqrt{u}} du$$

$$\int \left( u^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \right)du$$

$$\int u^{\frac{3}{2}} du + \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} du$$

I'll let you take it from here